# Python dictionary update values and elements in each iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, dictionary

I have a main dictionary named `summary`.

```
summary = {}
```

And I have another dictionary 'temp' that is generated with different key value pairs in each iteration of a loop.

For example:
In first iteration of loop,

```
temp = {'a': 10, 'b': 50}
```

In second iteration of loop,

```
temp = {'a': 40, 'b': 20, 'c'=100}
```

I want the main dictionary `summary` to be updated after each iteration with the elements of `temp`. If a key IS NOT already present in `summary`, the key-value pair from `temp` should be entered into it. If a key IS already present in 'summary', then the value needs to be added to the existing value for that key in 'summary'.

So my desired result here after 2 iterations is,

```
summary = {'a': 50, 'b': 70, 'c'=100}
```

I tried to use update function, but it was not working

Comment: `I tried to use update function, but it was not working`: What have you tried? Post your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dict.update` here isn't going to give you your desired results, because that completely overrides values in the dictionary. What you want to do is add the values to the existing key-value pairs in the `summary` at the end of each loop iteration.

I would use a `defaultdict` for the `summary` such that you can easily add to it from each `temp` dict created without having to explicitly initialize the key to `0`. At the end of each iteration, take the entries from each `temp` dict and add them one at a time to the summary.

Example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

temp_dicts = [{'a': 10, 'b': 50}, {'a': 40, 'b': 20, 'c': 100}]

summary = defaultdict(int)

for temp in temp_dicts:
    for key, value in temp.items():
        summary[key] += value

print(dict(summary))
```

Outputs:

```
{'a': 50, 'b': 70, 'c': 100}
```

You could also achieve a similar result with a `Counter`, which supports keeping track of the counts for keys. Using the `|` operator you can append directly from the `temp` dicts

```
from collections import Counter

temp_dicts = [{'a': 10, 'b': 50}, {'a': 40, 'b': 20, 'c': 100}]

summary = Counter()

for temp in temp_dicts:
    summary |= temp

print(dict(summary))
```

Comment: Thanks, the loop with defaultdict worked perfectly. I was just wondering if there was a prebuilt function in python to do it or a one line function. But the looping method works just fine as well.

Comment: @planetex See the comment about the `Counter`! It is a specialized class, similar to the defaultdict more specific to this type of use-case. The defaultdict is a more generalized tool helping with a wider set of problems.